# installing an application from a command line on a mac

Tags: command, installation

installing an application from a command line on a mac

Hope someone can help.

I need to reinstall Final Cup Studio 2 on my mac.  Since I've change to the new operating system: Lion, I'm not able to reinstall the application from the installations disks because PowerPC applications are no longer supported with Lion.  One suggested solution, seems to work with many people, is to instal the program from the command line with the following argument:

$ sudo installer -package /Volumes/Final\ Cut\ Studio/Installer/FinalCutStudio.mpkg -target /

After what appear to be a "successful installation", the program is no where to be found :(.
Another solution was to add the specific PATH to were the application/s are going to reside:

/Volumes/[MainDrive]/Applications/

The problem with this is that I don't know hoy to add the additional information to the command line.

I've created a subfolder named:  FINALCUTSTUDIO2 under the Applications Folder and would like to give a command to install the applicationto that particular

Answer (score 0):

Rosetta, the program that lets you run PowerPC binaries on Intel processors, was [taken out of OS X starting with Lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion#Dropped_features). There's no way to make it run on Lion, unfortunately, even if you got it installed somehow.

Comment: Yes there is.  Check this link: http://www.jeremyjohnstone.com/blog/2012-03-11-installing-final-cut-pro-studio-2-0-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion.html/comment-page-1#comments

Comment: All I need is for someone to let me know what the command is to do it from a Terminal.

Comment: I can assure you, unless there's a software update that makes it a Universal binary, it won't work. Someone on that same link even had the same problem. But in any case, as long as the installation was successful, it should be somewhere in your Applications folder. Try `find /Applications -iname final*`

Comment: Assuming it could work, as seen on the link I sent.  Would you know what the right argument would be to install the application to that particular folder through the Command line?  Thanks

Comment: As per the installer [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/installer.8.html), you can only set the target *volume*, not target *folder*. Please try the `find` line I posted above.

Comment: Seems it did, but cant see it :(

Comment: /Applications/Final Cut Pro Additional Easy Setups.localized
/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app
/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Final Cut Pro
/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Plugins/FinalTouchExport.bundle
/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Plugins/FinalTouchExport.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinalTouchExport
/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Plugins/FinalTouchExport.bundle/Contents/Resources/FinalTouchExport.rsrc
/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Final Cut Pro Settings

Comment: That would mean it found Final Cut Pro. It should be in the `Applications` folder named `Final Cut Pro`.

Comment: I haven't upgraded yet to Lion, so I'm not sure, but it may not show up because Lion won't run PowerPC programs. But the output from `find` shows it is there. Try doing a software update and seeing if there's any updates that make it Universal. Failing that, try logging out and in again, and if that doesn't work, I don't see any way to make FCP2 work in Lion, because as I said they took out PPC emulation support.